# Can I get Illustrator to save an SVG and retain a transparent stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, svg

Below is an icon comprised of two images. The top image has a 1px transparent stroke "knocking out" the layer below. This is fine as an .ai file. 
[image]

However when I save as .svg the stroke has disappeared.
[image]

Is there any way of saving an .svg file and keeping the transparent stroke masking the layer below?

Thanks.

Comment: you might want to actually 'expand' this knocking out effect by taking the flag shape, `Object>Path>Offset Path` and subtract the resulting shape from the house. That way, you actually change the shape and the effect will show up in all possible file formats.

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer, then. Glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

It is a better idea to actually change your shapes—cut out the enlarged flag shap from the house shape:

1. Select your green flag shape;
2. Remove all strokes;
3. Choose `Object > Path > Offset Path...` and choose an offset value;
4. This creates a copy of your flag shape, enlarged as if it had an incorporated border of the thickness you specified. Select that shape (it's selected by default if you exit the `Offset Path` dialog box);
5. Also select your house shape (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on it with the Black Arrow tool (<kbd>V</kbd>));
6. In the `Pathfinder` palette, click on `subtract`.

This way, the house shape is actually changed, and the knockout effect will show up in any kind of file.